# How to get a list of MySQL views?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to list all views in a database.

Initially I found and tried an [answer on the MySQL forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?100,81717,81728):

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.views
WHERE information_schema.views.table_schema LIKE 'view%';
```

How ever this doesn't work, returning an empty set. (I know they're in there!)

These also fail:

```
mysql> use information_schema;
Database changed
mysql> select * from views;
ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'mysql.bak'
mysql> select * from tables;
ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'mysql.bak'
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: [link](https://geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/mysql/tips_and_tricks/mysql_query_to_find_all_views_in_a_database.php) this may help

Answer (score 358, accepted):

```
SHOW FULL TABLES IN database_name WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';
```

[MySQL query to find all views in a database](http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/mysql/tips_and_tricks/mysql_query_to_find_all_views_in_a_database.php)

Comment: It is possible to leave the "IN database_name" away if you look for view in the currently selected DB.

Answer (score 38):

Here's a way to find all the views in *every* database on your instance:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';
```

Comment: If you want to restrict the search to a certain database to get an answer to the question posed add `AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'database_name'`.

Comment: To complement or retrieve more data about the view consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834016/how-to-get-a-list-of-mysql-views/58452006#58452006

Answer (score 19):

To **complement** about to get more info about a specific view

Even with the two valid answers

```
SHOW FULL TABLES IN your_db_name WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';

SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW' AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'your_db_name';
```

You can apply the following (I think is better):

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.VIEWS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'your_db_name';
```

is better work directly with `information_schema.VIEWS` (observe now is **VIEWS** and not **TABLES** anymore), thus you can retrieve more data, use `DESC VIEWS` for more details:

```
+----------------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type                            | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| TABLE_CATALOG        | varchar(64)                     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TABLE_SCHEMA         | varchar(64)                     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TABLE_NAME           | varchar(64)                     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| VIEW_DEFINITION      | longtext                        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CHECK_OPTION         | enum('NONE','LOCAL','CASCADED') | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| IS_UPDATABLE         | enum('NO','YES')                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DEFINER              | varchar(93)                     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SECURITY_TYPE        | varchar(7)                      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT | varchar(64)                     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| COLLATION_CONNECTION | varchar(64)                     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

For example observe the `VIEW_DEFINITION` field, thus you can use in action:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, VIEW_DEFINITION 
FROM information_schema.VIEWS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'your_db_name';
```

Of course you have more fields available for your consideration.

Answer (score 9):

```
 select * FROM information_schema.views\G;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try moving that `mysql.bak` directory out of `/var/lib/mysql` to say `/root/` or something.  It seems like mysql is finding that and it may be causing that `ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'mysql.bak'` error.

Answer (score 1):

The error your seeing is probably due to a non-MySQL created directory in MySQL's data directory. MySQL maps the database structure pretty directly onto the file system, databases are mapped to directories and tables are files in those directories.

The name of the non-working database looks suspiciously like someone has copied the mysql database directory to a backup at some point and left it in MySQL's data directory. This isn't a problem as long as you don't try and use the database for anything. Unfortunately the information schema scans all of the databases it finds and finds that this one isn't a real database and gets upset.

The solution is to find the mysql.bak directory on the hard disk and move it well away from MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to find all View:

SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_type = 'VIEW'

Answer (score 1):

If you created any view in Mysql databases then you can simply see it as you see your all tables in your particular database.

write:

```
--mysql> SHOW TABLES;
```

you will see list of tables and views of your database.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for fetching all views tables
**select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS**

And the below query worked for fetching all views for a specific table.
**select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS where TABLE_CATALOG='<table_name>'**