# Check if MySQL table exists or not

Tags: php, mysql, exists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL check if a table exists without throwing an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525784/mysql-check-if-a-table-exists-without-throwing-an-exception)

I have a dynamic mysql query builder in my project that creates select queries from different tables.
I need to check if the current processing table exists or not.
Imagine that my tables are table1, table2, and table3. My code is something like this:

```
<?php
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 3 ; $i++) {
   $this_table = 'table'.$i;
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $this_table");
   // ...
}
?>
```

How can I do this check (Please tell me the simplest way).

Comment: I believe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525784/mysql-check-if-a-table-exists-without-throwing-an-exception) has the answer

Comment: I don't know why this question must have 3 vote down ...

Comment: Perhaps because it was duplicated. Check the link I posted above.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Updated mysqli version:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$table."'")) {
    if($result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo "Table exists";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Table does not exist";
}
```

Original mysql version:

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$table."'"))==1) 
    echo "Table exists";
else echo "Table does not exist";
```

Referenced from the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-tablename.php).

Comment: note that queries to information_schema (like SHOW TABLES) for DB with lots of tables use a lot of CPU, even if files are cached. True for the latest 5.6.x.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Is this working on Views table?

Comment: @ßiansorÅ.Ålmerol The answer on this question help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834016/how-to-get-a-list-of-mysql-views

Comment: @sivann so what is the better option? Select from table?

Comment: @VitorGuerreiro Use another DB or if you only create and not delete tables, write a mysql-proxy script which caches the successful (table actually exists) queries and replies instantly, and forwards only queries where table does not exist in its cache (or in db).

Comment: @VitorGuerreiro Example for you here: http://pastebin.com/3gTm0mkF

Answer (score 12):

Taken from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525784/mysql-check-if-a-table-exists-without-throwing-an-exception)

```
$checktable = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$this_table'");
$table_exists = mysql_num_rows($checktable) > 0;
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (I'm genuinely asking you to, I'm NOT a database expert by any means, I'm actually wondering) but isn't it possible for a table to exist but have 0 rows? Doesn't this check if it exists AND has at least one row, as opposed to testing if it exists? Will the value of `$checktable` be different if the table doesn't exist at all vs. it existing without any content?

Comment: @JimboJonny Since nobody has responded I'll address this - the query searches for tables (this will be running a query against the information schema - worth a google), and as such the rows it returns will _be_ tables. Therefore if the table exists, it will show as a row in the result of this query. The number of rows in the table is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 10):

```
$query = mysqli_query('SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ("table1","table2","table3") AND TABLE_SCHEMA="yourschema"');
$tablesExists = array();
while( null!==($row=mysqli_fetch_row($query)) ){
    $tablesExists[] = $row[0];
}
```

Comment: You can replace `TABLE_SCHEMA="yourschema"` by `TABLE_SCHEMA=database()`

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname");

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
{
    $arr[] = $row[0];
}

if(in_array($table,$arr))
{
  echo 'Table exists';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this query and then check the results.

```
$query = 'show tables like "test1"';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $this_table") or die (mysql_error());
```

or this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $this_table") or die ("Table does not exists!");
```

or this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $this_table");

if(!$query)
   echo "The ".$this_table." does not exists";
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice!! Works well!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL way:

`SHOW TABLES LIKE 'pattern';`

There's also a deprecated PHP function for listing all db tables, take a look at
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php

Checkout that link, there are plenty of useful insight on the comments over there.