# Checking that a table exists on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check whether a table exists, and if so then do some actions.  I keep on getting an error telling me that the table does not exist rather than completing my check. Here is the code:

```
$tableExists = $db->prepare("SHOW TABLES LIKE $table_array");
$tableExists->execute();
if($tableExists->rowCount() > 0) {
   // do some code
 } else {
   echo "Unable to add because table does not exists";
}
```

UPDATE:
Per suggestions below, I now do the following:

```
$tableExists = $db->prepare("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?"); 
$tableExists->execute(array($table_array)); 
if(!is_null($tableExist)) { 
    //do something
} else {
    echo "table does not exist;
}
```

However, the if statement does not seem to work to determine whether the table exists or not.  What else could I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using the `information_schema` to ask if the table exists. Something like

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  information_schema 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = "$table_array"
```

Take a look through everything the `information_schema` holds, you will be pleasantly surprised by the information it has stored about your databases :)

Comment: That... Is... Awesome... And to say that I took that table as part of the phpMyAdmin intrusive tables... :)

Comment: My name is Alfred Salketer Arengard (Yeh, I know...), and I "aprove" this answer... @jaczes ;)

Comment: OK, that works, but how do I test if it is empty? This is what I have: $tableExists = $db->prepare("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?");
  $tableExists->execute(array($table_array));
  
  if(!is_null($tableExist)) {

Comment: You can do `Select COUNT(*) from ...` -> 1 and more = there is table, 0 = no table

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain myself correctly. How do I check if the result for the query to check if the table exists is positive or not?

Comment: What is returned by your query when the table does not exists so that I can check for that? - @jaczes

Comment: i didnt reply because im bad in PHP... 1(or more)= there is table, 0 = no table

Comment: got it to work, just changed the if to '($getfields->rowCount() == 0)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$table."'"))==1) 
    echo "Table exists";
else echo "Table does not exist";
```

ref: [check if MySQL table exists or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008299/check-if-mysql-table-exists-or-not)

Comment: Thanks, I searched and had not found that other answer

Comment: do you know how I can check whether the table exists given the update above?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```sql
select case when (select count(*) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME='offices') = 1 then 'exists' else 'does not exist' end
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain that again?  This is what I have now, I just don't know how to test whether the result for the query is valid (table exists) or not. $tableExists = $db->prepare("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?"); $tableExists->execute(array($table_array)); if(!is_null($tableExist)) {//do code}

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
select * from table_schema //this is your database name    
where table_name // your table name    
= '$table_array'
```

Hope this works for you.