# php upload file path to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So, I am creating a very simply uploader where I take in a file/name/description and to store to store the file to the server and name/desc/filepath. 
This is what my database looks like:

Basically, i take in a file, name, and description and want the file to be stored in the server. While the path/name/desc to be stored into mySQL.  I also want an incrementing ID.  I have a db named "test". And want to post to "test_table".  The database is already created but I need to check if the table exists, if not, create it.   I think I have the basics of mySQL correct below, but I need to know how to check for table/create if needed and how to set the path variable.  Thanks in advance!

Also, how do I increment the ID variable in mysql with each entry? does that happen automatically or .. ?

solved

Comment: Why do you want to create the table in your code?doesn't it already exist?

Comment: here your file name is always blank because $name is POST data ..you need $name=$_FILES(['fileToupload']['name']);

Comment: No, it does not. And its not my database just running the php side of things.

Comment: Mayank Vadiya, the $name field is seperate, I will attach my html code as well.

Comment: You need to run the query.... All you're doing is creating the insertion script variable .... `$sql`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to upload your file to the server before inserting in the database:

```
if ($_FILES['fileinput']['name']!="") {  

                    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileinput']["tmp_name"])) {                   
                        $name = date("Y-m-d : H:i:s")." ".$_FILES['fileinput']['name']; 
                        $filevalue = $nameoffile;
                            $path =$file_save_path.$nameoffile;

                            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file".$i]["tmp_name"], $uploaddir.$nameoffile)) {       

                                 $sql = "INSERT INTO test_table (name, desc, path)  VALUES ($name, $desc, $path)";
                                mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
                            } else { 

                                echo "File Upload Error. Please Try again";                             
                            }
                        }

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

To check, if a table exists, see this question: [check if MySQL table exists or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008299/check-if-mysql-table-exists-or-not)
Essentially, this is the code to check:

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$table."'"))==1) 
    echo "Table exists";
else echo "Table does not exist";
```

To autoinc the ID just use the autoincrement attribute to the ID field, see the documentation here for more info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE test_tabel MODIFY COLUMN ID INT auto_increment
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: OP is using `PDO` and you're using a deprecated Library (`mysql_*`), please keep your answer relevant and up to date to prevent any future issues the OP could face from using this library :-)

Comment: @Darren These are just examples on how to do the job, taken from prev answers here on SO ... i think, one can easily extract the sql from the code and port it onto his needs