# List of views in mysql

Tags: mysql

I created some views in `mysql` but I don't quite remember their names. Is there a way to look them up as you would a table, i.e. (`show tables;`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate question with an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8253426/2145211)

```
SHOW FULL TABLES IN database_name WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';
```

Comment: In the future, if it is a duplicate question, please flag or close the question as a duplicate instead of posting an answer. Thanks!