# Subquerying MYSQL to select All Databases from server

Tags: mysql, view, inner-join, mariadb

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834016/how-to-get-a-list-of-mysql-views) topic before asking, and I found it was helpful just in a certain point, and now it's not enough.

I have a lot of databases in a MariaDB server, and one of the registered views is broken, giving me "Invalid references" error.

What I need is to find out what View is broken, considering that this error is preventing me to run my Backup routine, and MariaDB log shows only "Database (Got error: 1049) (Locktable)"

Now that I have a list of my views, is there any way to "select *" all of them, in different databases?

I've tried something like this:

```
select *  from TABLE_SCHEMA where (select TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where TABLE_TYPE like 'VIEW');
```

But I know it will not work since I'm not providing a specific database.

I think a Inner-Join would solve this case, but I can't figure out how to accomplish it...

By the way, if there's a better approach to find what View is defective, I would appreciate it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the only answer was removed by it's contributor, I've developed a ugly but effective workaround:

1. I've created a file with both Database and View names, using query provided below:

`` mysql -p*** -e "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.`TABLES` WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW'" > views.txt ``

2. This saves to file "views.txt" the flow with the information I need to run a basic Select in a View, so I did the following:

`while IFS= read -r line; do mysql -p*** -e "select * from $(echo $line | awk '{print $1}').$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}') LIMIT 1" 2>> errors.txt; echo $line >> errors.txt; done < views.txt`

I know it's ugly, but it will run a "select *" in every database.table or database.view listed in "views.txt", returning only first line of this query.

It provided me a effective test in my server, which showed me what view was broken:

> ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table '.' doesn't exist

If you're facing similar problems, I hope you may find a better way to solve this.