# Query to find out tables used in views

Tags: mysql, view, metadata

The solution(s) to the SO question [How to get a list of MySQL views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834016/how-to-get-a-list-of-mysql-views) give a query that can list all the views in a mysql database.

Is there a way to find out what tables were used in constructing those views ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well got it answered by my colleague

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE VIEW_DEFINITION like '%table_name%'
```