# Check if view exists in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

I have a mysql view called `records_latest`. What query can I use to check if this view already exists in mysql database?

I create this view in a script during start-up. I do not wish to create it more than once. So, I need to check if the view exists or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list of MySQL views?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834016/how-to-get-a-list-of-mysql-views)

Comment: information_schema.views https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/views-table.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To show a list of views that are in you database the

```
SHOW FULL TABLES IN youdatabasename WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE '%VIEW%';
```

if you want to create a view with that name and you don't care how the view was before you can use the

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  records_latest ....
```

this will delete the previous view if it exists and then will create the view again

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW records_latest...
```

This will make sure it refreshes on startup and will not duplicate if it exists

Comment: THANKS!! This is so much more efficient. Just a one-liner to solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry I did not mark your answer as the answer. I think the other answer provided more information, so I marked the other one even though you were faster.

Comment: @LitAiy Not a problem :D

Answer (score 0):

To list all view:

```sql
SHOW FULL TABLES IN db_name_here WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';
```

Filter by table or view name, no need re-creation:

```sql
SHOW FULL TABLES IN db_name_here LIKE 'table_or_view_name_here';
```