# Only select tables from database not views

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to select only table name not view names from the database using "show tables from database; " but views and tables are displayed together so what can I do?

Comment: Invert the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834016/how-to-get-a-list-of-mysql-views and learn how to google

Comment: Actually what you are trying to do. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
show full tables where table_type <> 'VIEW'
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fbfcb/1

The full syntax and options can be found in the [reference manual - SHOW TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this as follows:

```
SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_Type != 'VIEW'
```

You can further refer to the MySQL [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html) for any other modifications / requirements.

Hope this answers your question well!